# Reading first line by getchar() in c

Tags: c

I want to read first line by `getchar()` but compiler tell me that array A is int type. How can I save my first line char by char in array using `getchar`?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
   FILE *fp;
   int i=0;
   char A[200];
   int c;

   fp = fopen("input.txt", "r");

   while ((c=getchar()) != '\n') && i<200) {
      A[i]=(char)c;
      i++;
   }
   for(i=0; i<200; i++) {
      printf("%s", A[i]);
   }
}
```

Comment: `char A[200];` *was* `int A[200];` before you edited the Q within the 5-minute time limit, but it makes nonsense of the question. Please post **your actual code** not shifting sand. As witnessed by *"compiler tell me that array A is int type"*

Comment: i made it and there is output �ȡ,�� �,������������.N=��@��������������t,��ȡ,��M@����@@@����� :)

Comment: What in Gaben's great gift is that?

Answer (score 2):

Your reading is (almost) fine, the biggest issue is *printing*.

Before fixing it, though, you should change the call of `getchar` to [`fgetc(fp)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fgetc.html) - something you probably meant to do, because you used `fopen`.

If you would like to print your line character-by-character, you need to use `%c` instead of `%s` format specified, ans stop iterating when you reach the length of the string that you have read. The `%s` specifier is also fine, as long as you null-terminate your string. It lets you avoid the loop, too:

```
A[i] = '\0';
printf("%s\n", A);
```

With printing out of the way, here are a few other things that you need to fix:

1. Allocate an extra `char` for null terminator:

   ```
   char A[201];
   ```

You could also stop reading upon reaching character 199 in your loop.

2. Make sure that the program stops reading when you reach `EOF`:

   ```
   while ((c=fgetc(fp)) != '\n') && c != EOF && i<200) {
       ...
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

As dasblinkenlight said, the %s specifier is used for strings while the %c is used for char. Therefore, your print statement should be

```
printf("%c\n",A[I]);
```

To ensure that the file has not ended, you could also use

```
!feof(fp)
```

in your while loop. If the file you were reading from contained less than 200 characters, you would run into problems. The feof function checks for the end of the file to ensure you wont read data after the file is ended.

Answer (score 0):

you can give it a try with something like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp;
    int i=0;
    char A[200];
     int c;

  fp = fopen("input.txt", "r");

   while ((c=getchar()) != '\n' && i<200 )
     {
        A[i]=(char)c;
        i++;
     };
  for(int j=0; j<i; j++) // print only those item available in array 
   {
        printf("%c", A[j]);
   }
}
```